# Is there a generic way to work with optimistic locking using Hibernate/Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using hibernate's @Version annotation for optimistic locking. My usual use case for updating something in DB looks like this:

1. Open a transaction (using @Transactional)
2. Select entities I need to change
3. Check if I can make the needed changes (validation step)
4. Do changes
5. Save everything (Spring Data JPA repository save() method), commit transaction
6. If I catch any of OptimisticLockException, then I have to retry everything from step 1 (until successful save or fail on validation step, and not more than X times)

This algorithm looks quite common for any kind of optimistic locking processing. Is there a generic way using hibernate or spring data jpa to do these retries/handling of optimistic locking failures or should I write method like this myself? I mean something like (but not literally):

```
boolean trySaveUntilDoneOrNotOptimisticLockingExceptionOccur(Runnable codeWhichSelectsValidatesUpdatesAndSavesDataButWithoutOptimisticLockingProcessing, int maxOptimisticLockingRetries)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is tagged with `spring-data-jpa`, I will answer from Spring world.

Just have a look at `@Retryable`. I find it quite useful for exactly the same use case you describe. This is my usual pattern:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 7, 
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50), 
            include = { TransientDataAccessException.class,
                        RecoverableDataAccessException.class }
)
public class MyService {

    // all methods in this service are now transactional and automatically retried.

}
```

You can play with backoff options, of course.

Check out [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) for further examples on `@Retryable`.